# Pay stubs for Schengen tourist Visa at Netherlands VFS in US

Tags: schengen, tourist-visas, schengen-visas, vfs-global

I recently took appointment for Schengen tourist visa at Netherlands VFS in SF. The appointment letter had a checklist of documents. It says for employed people, we need to show last three bank statements or pay stubs. Is it fine to show just pay stubs as it says 'or' between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just show them the pay stubs.

Have fun in the Netherlands =)